# Variable 'details' is used before it has been assigned a value.

Tags: vb.net, rowdetails

Variable `details` is used before it has been assigned a value. What is the problem with `details`?

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Public Class Main
    Private SelectedItem As ListViewItem
    Dim data As String

    Dim strpriority As String
    Dim task As String
    Dim createdate As String
    Dim duedate As String

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        AddTask.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub HistoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles HistoryToolStripMenuItem.Click
        History.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim fpath As String
        Dim splitdata
        fpath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
        Dim filepath As String
        filepath = fpath & "task.txt"
        Dim details As String
        details = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filepath)
        splitdata = Split(details, vbCrLf)
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To UBound(splitdata)
            lblTaskName.Items.Add(splitdata(i))
        Next

        lblTime.Enabled = True
        Timer1.Interval = 10
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        lblTime.Text = TimeOfDay
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        End
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRemove_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
        If lblTaskName.SelectedItem = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please select a record")

        Else

            If lblTaskName.Items.Count > 0 Then
                If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to delete this record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                    lblTaskName.Items.Remove(lblTaskName.SelectedItem.ToString())

                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Operation Cancelled")

                End If
            End If

        End If

        Try

            Dim fpath As String
            fpath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
            Dim filepath As String
            filepath = fpath & "task.txt"
            Dim details As String
            If lblTaskName.Items.Count > 0 Then
                details = lblTaskName.Items(0)
                Dim i As Integer
                For i = 1 To lblTaskName.Items.Count - 1

                    details = details & vbCrLf & lblTaskName.Items(i)

                Next
            End If
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(filepath, details, False)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Values Can't be inserted this time")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function filepaths() As String
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `btnRemove_Click` method in this part:

```
Dim details As String
If lblTaskName.Items.Count > 0 Then
    details = lblTaskName.Items(0)
```

If the condition evaluates to false, the `details` variable is used before it is initialized, because it is only set in the `if` block up to now.

I suppose you want to move the following line into the `if` block to solve the problem:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(filepath, details, False)
```

Alternatively, you can come up with a default value for `details` so that it is set in any case. For performance reasons, you can set the default value (e.g. a text or `String.Empty`) in an `else` branch:

```
Dim details As String
If lblTaskName.Items.Count > 0 Then
     ' ...
Else
    details = "Default Value"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to think through the flow of your program. Consider this code:

```
Dim details As String
If lblTaskName.Items.Count > 0 Then
    details = lblTaskName.Items(0)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To lblTaskName.Items.Count - 1
        details = details & vbCrLf & lblTaskName.Items(i)
    Next
End If
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(filepath, details, False)
```

You declare the `details` variable at the top. Then you check that there is at least 1 item in the `lblTaskName` control. If that test passes, then you assign the first item to `details`. **But what if that test doesn't pass?** What if there are 0 items in the `lblTaskName` control? In that case, the interior of the `If` block never runs, and nothing ever gets stored in `details`. Then in the final line, you try to use the value of the `details` variable *outside of the `If` block. This is illegal because it may not have been assigned a value.

Perhaps you meant for that `WriteAllText` line to be *inside* of `If` block? Otherwise, you'll need to add an `Else` clause to your `If` statement to handle the case where there are 0 items in `lblTaskName`.

---

Aside from that, stylistically speaking, you should prefer to initialize variables at the time of declaration whenever possible. So for example, instead of writing:

```
    Dim fpath As String
    Dim splitdata
    fpath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Dim filepath As String
    filepath = fpath & "task.txt"
    Dim details As String
    details = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filepath)
    splitdata = Split(details, vbCrLf)
```

write it as:

```
    Dim fpath As String       = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Dim filepath As String    = fpath & "task.txt"
    Dim details As String     = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filepath)
    Dim splitdata() As String = Split(details, vbCrLf)
```

(I'm OCD, so I line up my equals signs. That part is totally optional.)

It doesn't make the code run any faster, but it does make it easier to read! More importantly, it decreases the potential for bugs.